# Por que a saída echo não está imprimindo na tela? (A página fica em branco)

Tags: php

Galera, alguém sabe me dizer o porque de quando eu entrar no meu arquivo php (localhost/teste.php) não aparece literalmente nada e fica tudo em branco? Meu arquivo é ultra simples que fiz só pra testar:

```
<?
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo    "as";
?>
```

Comment: Você não vai dizer que esse *script* é PHP com `<?php`,?

Comment: Cara, ingenuidade total a minha, é porque to começando com php aqui e tava fazendo uns teste ... Brigadão :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não iniciou o php da forma correta. O certo seria:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo    "as";

?>
```

Comment: Meu deus ... Não acredito que era tão simples assim. Brigadão mano :)